# how to get table name as row value

Tags: postgresql, select, union

i have two tables customer and suppliers , i am trying to get city,company_name,contact_name  and org name from both the table using union i also want to create a column relationship  and want to have values customer or suppliers depending on which table they come from

unable to get a way around

please help me

my code is

```
select city,company_name,contact_name 
from customers
union
select city,company_name,contact_name
from suppliers
```

i know this is very simple and incomplete code please help me .

i do not have any clues to try .

Comment: What do you mean by "column relationship"?

Comment: Btw the common way to get the tablename into that query is to simply provide it as a constant. E.g. `select 'Customer', city... from customers`